# redirect From wizard to One2many field

Tags: odoo, odoo-10

hi any help please I have a button to create new wizard

```xml
<button name="evaluer" string="Evaluer" type="object" class="oe_highlight" attrs="{'invisible': [('bool_evaluate', '=', True)]}" />
```

how can I redirect From wizard  the evaluation created to  field one2many evaluation_line

```py
class etude(models.Model):
    _name = 'etude.risque'

    evaluation_line = fields.One2many('risque.evaluation', 'evaluation_id', 'Evaluation')
```

function create

```py
@api.multi
def evaluer(self):
    test = self.env['risque.evaluation'].create({'risque_etude': self.risque.nom_risque,
                                                 'client': self.client.name,
                                                 'etude': rub_list,
                                                 'note_globale': ''
                        })
    return {
         'name': 'Evaluation',
         'view_type': 'form',
         'view_mode': 'tree,form',
         'view_id': form_id,
         'views': [(form_id, 'form')],
         'res_model': 'risque.evaluation',
         'type': 'ir.actions.act_window',
         'res_id': test.id,
         'target': 'new',
         'flags': {'initial_mode': 'edit', 'create': False},
         'context': self.env.context,
     }
```

Comment: It is not entirely clear what is the problem? Doesn't your approach work? What is the value of `form_id`, how is it calculated?